# Django simple_history "missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'"

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I've tried to install simple_history to my existing Django app- but have encountered a few errors including the below. I've encountered these errors when attempting to run "makemigrations".

I could fix this by adding the on_delete to the package models file- though because of the other issues I encountered before this one, it seems like there might be a deeper issue.

My django version is: (2, 2, 7, 'final', 0)
Python version is 3.7.3

```
    'history_user': CurrentUserField(related_name=rel_nm),
  File "appname/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simple_history/models.py", line 26, in __init__
    super(CurrentUserField, self).__init__(User, null=True, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `on_delete` first and then reviewing the error message? It is unclear what the deeper issue you mention relates to without understanding the wider background context.

Comment: @WayneLambert When I do, I get another unrelated error. This was actually the third error I fixed. The first two were related to the imports within the simple_history models.py file. I had to add "simple_history." before the manager and registration inputs

Comment: I wonder if the error has anything to do with the fact that you're using a custom user. Have you looked at https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#tracking-custom-users

Comment: @RossMechanic Thanks for the response Ross! That's the strange thing- I'm not sure what 'history_user' is. I actually only have one user type in my app- and don't plan on utilizing the user feature with 'simple_history'

Answer (score 0):

This was a very silly mistake on my part. I installed the python package 'simple_history' instead of 'django-simple-history'... Simple yet crucial mistake...